# NDK at ~/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle did not have a source.properties file in Flutter

Tags: java, android, react-native, flutter, flutter-dependencies

when I run the Flutter app using vscode it's Getting this error in CMD

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:stripDebugDebugSymbols'.
  NDK at C:\Users\jupun\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle did not have a source.properties file

This is the Build.Gradle file

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
'''
this is the local.properties
sdk.dir=C\:\\Users\\jupun\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk
```

Answer (score 2):

i face this problem i solved it be deleting the folder  ndk-bundle
in this path
C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle